# Is it okay to conjugate the verb 'let' (means 'rent') in this way?

Tags: verbs, passive-voice, infinitives, to-infinitive

'To let' seems like an irregular and special infinitive-verb phrase, which can express the meaning of a passive verb as an intransitive one.

> This house is to let.

Comment: Oxford gives the use of _let_ to mean 'hire out' as British. _To let_ means _available for rent_ - I don't think it's an infinitive.

Comment: @KateBunting I disagree. In a sentence like "This book is to read at the airport", **to** functions as an infinitive marker, and also indicates purpose or use.

Comment: Yes, "let" is a verb in "This house is to let", where "to let" is an infinitival clause functioning as predicative complement of "be"

Answer (score 1):

**[to](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/to)** is a preposition that has many possible meanings: many of these also involve acting as an infinitive marker.  One of these meanings is to express use or purpose:

> I always take a book **to** read on the plane.

Here is a sentence with the same structure as the one in your question:

> This book is **to** read on the plane.

Comment: I think it's better to say that this "to" is a subordinator, a special marker for VPs of infinitival clauses. In _I always take a book [to read on the plane]_ the bracketed element is an infinitival relative clause modifying "book". The relativised element is direct object of "read".